# How do I transform a multi-level list into a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
a = [('A', 'V', 'C'), ('A', 'D', 'D')]
```

And I want to create another list that transforms `a` into:

```
['AVC', 'ADD']
```

How would I go on to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in a list comprehension (works in both Python 2.x and 3.x):

```
>>> a = [('A', 'V', 'C'), ('A', 'D', 'D')]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in a]
['AVC', 'ADD']
```

Answer (score 22):

You could map `str.join` to each `tuple` in `a`:

Python 2:

```
>>> map(''.join, a)
['AVC', 'ADD']
```

In Python 3, `map` is an iterable object so you'd need to materialise it as a `list`:

```
>>> list(map(''.join, a))
['AVC', 'ADD']
```

Comment: Returns a map object on my machine.

Answer (score 6):

Using `reduce` is another option:

```
>>> a = [('A','V','C'), ('A','D','D')]
```

In Python 2:

```
>>> [reduce(lambda x, y: x + y , i) for i in a]
['AVC', 'ADD']
```

In Python 3 (Thanks for eugene's suggestion):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> [reduce(lambda x, y: x + y , i) for i in a]
['AVC', 'ADD']
```

Comment: A very inefficient option, though.

Comment: And In Python3 you'd need `from functools import reduce`.

Comment: and you can replace your lambda with `operator.concat`

Comment: @chepner source? why would it be less efficient? no matter how you look at it, you still have to add elements to one another

Comment: Because you are 1) repeated calling a user-defined function (cf. replacing `lambda` with `operator.itemgetter` for things like the `key` argument to `sorted`) and 2) allocating a new Python `str` object every for each character. `join` takes the list of strings, allocates a *single* string object for the result, and fills it in using its input. (That is, everything is done at the C level, not the Python level).